# I can't play an UILocalNotification sound from NSDocumentsDirectory on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm having an issue with `UILocalNotification` (but it is the same with the Push notifications).
I'm only allowed to play sounds from the bundle of the app. For the purpose of my app, I'd like to play a sound from the `NSDocumentsDirectory`. I know that it was possible prior to iOS 6.

My question is: has anyone found a solution / hack to do it on iOS 7/8 ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are a couple key points to address but it's best you provide the code you are working with so we as answerers don't go out of our way to provide a solutions your not interested in or have already attempted